# Adding hindi font from excel file into database using php

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv, utf-8

I have a csv file called as hinditext.csv which contains text in hindi. 
Now when I try this code it enter data but in ?? ?? ?? way. I tried setting `utf`. But that doesn't seems to work.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

```
<?php
    $file = fopen("hinditest.csv","r");
    $arr = fgetcsv($file);

    fclose($file);
    header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' ); 
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('test');    

    mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
    mysql_query('SET names=utf8');
    mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
    mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
    mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
    mysql_query('SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci');
    $sql = "insert into hindi(data) values ('".$arr[0]."')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    echo '<br />Data inserted successfully.<br />'; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the database and table charsets and the columns' collation?

For Hindi I guess you could try utf8_unicode_ci. Something like this:

```
 CREATE DATABASE test
        CHARACTER SET utf8
        COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

 CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
    `first_name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Hi i tried this with excel files also but still they are not working. Am working on csv files.